# email enable SharePoint 2010 Team Discussion

Tags: email, team

When working with a SP 2010 Team Discussion (discussion within a Team Web site), it seems that by default, no email is ever sent to notify team members regarding anything occuring with the discussion. Basic googling on the topic didn't turn up much.

**Q:** Is there a way to "email enable" team discussions so that team members get notification of updates to the disucssion board, or better yet, be able to participate in the discussion entirely via email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connect to Outlook" is the option you are looking for.

-Navigate to the discussion board.
-Click the Library tab at the very top.
-Click the "Connect to Outlook" option. 
-Click Allow and Yes when prompted.
-It should be in your Outlook under SharePoint Lists section!